# Moving elements created in JS into another element created in JS

Tags: javascript

So I have a function that creates a div titled 'musiccard' within the 'content' div and after I have it pull JSON data and use that for the music data. For now it all currently resides in the content div and I was wondering on the best way to move it into the music card which is being created at the same time the data is being pulled.

Here's my js file:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  init();
  title();
  headerDescription();
});


 function init() {
  loadJSON(function(response) {
     var json = JSON.parse(response);
     var count = Object.keys(json.musics).length;
     for(var i=0; i<count; i++){

      var div = document.createElement("div");
       div.setAttribute("class", "musiccard");
       content.appendChild(div);

      var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
      h3.textContent = json.musics[i].title;
      content.appendChild(h3);

      var p = document.createElement("p");
      p.setAttribute("class", "albumruntime");
      p.innerHTML = 'Run Time:' + json.musics[i].running_time + 'min';
      content.appendChild(p);

      var p = document.createElement("p");
      p.setAttribute("class", "musicdescription");
      p.innerHTML = json.musics[i].description;
      content.appendChild(p);

       var img = document.createElement("img");
       img.src = json.musics[i].url;
       img.setAttribute("class", "albumart");
       content.appendChild(img);
     }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Where do you want to put the music cards you've created? You want to move them from `<div id="content">` to another div?

Comment: @Andy At the moment they are in the `<div id="content">` but I want all the other information that currently resides in the content div such as the title, image, description to go into the music card div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how you added the new `musiccard` to the `content` element you can add all those new elements to the `musiccard` element instead *before* you add it to `content`.

Some steps you can follow:

1) Grab the `content` element.

2) Create a [`document fragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment). This is useful if you're adding updating elements in a loop. Instead of adding all the elements to the DOM you add them to a fragment and add that single fragment to the DOM once the loop is complete. It's more efficient.

3) Create the `musiccard` element and add all the other new elements to it.

4) At the end of the loop add the `musiccard` to the fragment

5) After all the `musiccard`s have been added to the fragment, add the fragment to `content`.

> Note: JSON is what is returned from the server. Once you parse it it's no longer JSON. I renamed your `json` variable to `data` so it makes more sense. I also renamed `div` to `musiccard` so the code is easier to follow.

```js
function loaddata(callback) {
  const json = '{"musics": [{"title": "title1", "running_time": 10, "description": "Note1", "url": "http://bob.com" }]}';
  callback(json);
}

function init() {
  loaddata(function(response) {

    var data = JSON.parse(response);

    var count = Object.keys(data.musics).length;
    
    // grab the content div
    var content = document.getElementById('content');

    // create the fragment
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

      var musiccard = document.createElement("div");
      musiccard.setAttribute("class", "musiccard");

      var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
      h3.textContent = data.musics[i].title;
      
      // add the title to musiccard
      musiccard.appendChild(h3);

      var p = document.createElement("p");
      p.setAttribute("class", "albumruntime");
      p.innerHTML = 'Run Time:' + data.musics[i].running_time + 'min';
      
      // add runtime to musiccard
      musiccard.appendChild(p);

      var p = document.createElement("p");
      p.setAttribute("class", "musicdescription");
      p.innerHTML = data.musics[i].description;
      
      // add description to musiccard
      musiccard.appendChild(p);

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = data.musics[i].url;
      img.setAttribute("class", "albumart");

      // add img to musiccard
      musiccard.appendChild(img);

      // add completed musiccard to the fragment
      frag.appendChild(musiccard);

    }

    // add the fragment containing all the musiccards
    // to the content div
    content.appendChild(frag);

  });

}

init();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that creating the musiccard div at the same time as the data is pulled is inherently synchronous.  You want to use an asynchronous function to achieve the desired result, calling back the function creating the div once pulling the data from the json file is complete.

You could, perhaps, create a Promise which pulls the data and then returns the musiccard div, with the data displayed inside of it, passing this result - the response received - into the then() callback.

Here's a really informative article on using Promises:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: The question isn't about synchronous/asynchonous processes. The OP was simply adding new elements to the wrong parent element.